# How to override inline css from external class?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap `glyphicon` class:

```
.glyphicon {
    top: 1px;
    //...
}
```

For one single item, I want to override `top` property, inline with CSS:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="glyphicon.top:2px"></span>
```

I know this is not a standard way, but you got the idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="position: relative; top:2px"></span>
```

`CSS` positioning properties (top/right/bottom/left) works only when used with `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed` position.

[Detailed Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: `position:relative` was the key.

Answer (score 2):

For inline css you don't need selector:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" style="top:2px"></span>
```

Inline CSS selectors has highest priority and will overwrite external CSS.

---

*Side note*

For `top: 2px` to work element must be non-statically positioned - `position: [relative,absolute,fixed]`

Answer (score 0):

The most optimal is to always use css. And no styles on the page itself. Good practices are welcome at the end of a project ...

```
<div class="icono">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
</div>
```

css

```
.icono .glyphicon-home {
 top: 1px;
}
```